# How to add call schedule functionality iin django python?

Tags: python, django, web

I am new to python. I am developing a website in django framework. I have to add a "scheduling a call" functionality in my website in which the user can book a call (name, email, date and time) and also can see the booked slots in calender. I do not know how to do this nor i am able to find anything like this on the internet. Can anyone here help me for it?

Comment: Show us what you’ve tried. This site isn’t for free-floating advice.

Comment: then tell me a website for this. i havent tried. i dont know how to do it

Comment: There is no simple explanation for how to solve your particular request. You can start to learn web development here: https://expressjs.com/. Yo might be better off buying an already-built scheduling app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood your question but, if your question is about scheduling in Django You can use one of libraries that can help you, like [celery](https://celeryproject.org)

but, there is another easy method to add scheduled task in Django.
I use threads to do the job.
by creating a thread in main function to do your task like bellow code in manage.py in Django.

```
def periodic_check():
    while True:
        # some code ...
        time.sleep(500)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = threading.Thread(target=periodic_check, daemon=True)
    x.start()
    main()
```